# Dynamically create listviewgroup powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have a listview that I populate with the contents of a folder by running Get-ChildItem. I want to group items with listviewgroup based on which folder they are in. My problem is I can't seem to be able to do it dynamically.

For example I get with Get-ChildItem 5 folders ie:

\\1
\\2
\\3
\\4
\\5

So I want to create 5 groups etc etc. Below is the code I tried so far:

```
$getgroups = Get-ChildItem $path -Filter $whattosearchfor -Recurse:$recurse | % {split-path $_.FullName } | Sort-Object -Descending | select-object -Unique

  for($testingI = 1;$testingI -lt $getgroups.length;$testingI++){
      $testingII = $testingI
      $testingII     = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewGroup
      $testingII.Header = $_
      $testingII.Name   = $_
      [system.void]$listView1.Groups.Add($testingII)
  }
  #$getgroups | % {
  #    #$xCounter        = $_ 
  #    $xCounter        = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewGroup
  #    $xCounter.Header = $_
  #    $xcounter.Name   = $_
  #    $listView1.Groups.Add($xCounter)
  #    $x++
  # }
```

Comment: found a solution using hashtables

moderator can close the thread

thxxx

Comment: You can post your solution to help others with the same or a similar problem or you can just delete your question if you think it's not helpfull for others. ;-)

Comment: ...or, if you do not want to help others, you can delete your question. You don't need moderators for that.

Answer (score 0):

sorry my bad

here is the solution

```
    $xcounter = @{ }
    $getgroups = Get-ChildItem $path -Filter $whattosearchfor -Recurse:$recurse | % { split-path $_.FullName } | Sort-Object -Descending | select-object -Unique
    $getgroups | % {
        $temp = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewGroup
        $temp.Header = $_
        $temp.Name = $_
        $xCounter[$_] = $temp
        $listView1.Groups.Add($xCounter[$_])
    }
```